# How to get text from Combo box c# Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Whenever I'm trying to get text from combo box it extracts data like `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Abc`

How can I get only "Abc" ? I mean to say only value not entire stack trace.
my code seems like:-

XAML:-

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="/Vegomart;component/Images/#My type of font" Text="User Type:- " FontSize="18" Foreground="Black"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="userType" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontFamily="/Vegomart;component/Images/#My type of font" Width="170" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" Margin="40,0,0,0"  >
                <ComboBoxItem> Abc</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

C#:-

```
string value = userType.SelectedItem.ToString();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);
```

Your effort will be appreciated :).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ComboBoxItem> Abc</ComboBoxItem>` sets the `Content` to `Abc`, so you would need to cast your `SelectedItem` to `ComboBoxItem` and get that property.

(That the XAML sets the content can be seem in the base class [`ContentControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) which has a `ContentPropertyAttribute` that defines which property to set.)

Comment: No successful effort :(. Can you please prepare a XAML and C# code. It would be really help full to me :)

Comment: It's pretty much what KipMorgan wrote, except that you should *not* use [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) but rather `(ComboBoxItem)userType.SelectedItem`, etc.

Comment: It worked, Actually I tried something like this :-
var value = userType.SelectionBoxItem.ToString(); 
And it worked. Thank you guys for your effort.

Comment: Also: Would recommend looking into [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @MohammadHani: Nooo, don't do that, using `ToString` is never a good idea.

Comment: @H.B. just curious, why not `as`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett: It obfuscates problems if you use it like this. If you use `as` you should always check for `null` afterwards unless you just cast to a base type or implemented interface, which is safe.

Comment: why is it not considered as a good habit ? o.O actually I'm aware what kind of value will be fetched therefore, I used ToString();

Comment: @MohammadHani: `ToString`'s behavior is usually not guaranteed to be consistent and meant primarily for debug output only.

Comment: so what should I used instead of ToString ?

Comment: @MohammadHani: If you know the item content is a string just cast it using `(string)`.

Comment: Ok ok.. I got it. Thanks bro for guiding me :)

Comment: @H.B. Ah, I see -- InvalidCastException is more informative than NullReferenceException. Thanks.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Was about to add that, you have great inference skills :D

Answer (score 3):

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="userType" SelectionChanged="userType_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Abc"/>
        <ComboBoxItem>Bcd</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Then in code behind:

```
    private void userType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            var comboBoxItem = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
            if (comboBoxItem != null)
            {
                var content = comboBoxItem.Content;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, Please up vote my this question so that my ban can be removed. I will be really thankful to you please up vote my provided question in link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163837/datagrid-is-not-showing-data-just-adding-row

Answer (score 1):

You can get the content of the item:

```
ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)userType.SelectedItem;
string value = (string)item.Content;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);
```

Comment: Hey, Please up vote my this question so that my ban can be removed. I will be really thankful to you please up vote my provided question in link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163837/datagrid-is-not-showing-data-just-adding-row

Answer (score 1):

This should return the text of the selected item in the ComboBox.

```
    string value = userType.Text.ToString();
```

Comment: Hey, Please up vote my this question so that my ban can be removed. I will be really thankful to you please up vote my provided question in link:-
<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163837/datagrid-is-not-showing-data-just-adding-row