# Value's Not Appearing In Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

**What I'm trying to do?**
I'm working on project i.e. Online Stock/Shares Marketing. In which client will able to set some order and can see details on his/her screen. For this I'm using WPF + C# and using datagrid so all products, rates and all of its detail will be listed in that grid in a tabular form. And data will be fetched from Sql Server Management Studio. Moreover, I'm binding data in datagrid.
**What Problem I'm Facing?**
Problem I'm facing is that in datagrid rows are added but data is not appearing  in those rows. For example if there is 4 rows in database, same no. of rows is appearing on datagrid but empty rows are appearing :(.

XAML:-

```
 <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="pa" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding ProductName}" Width="2*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding ProductPrice}" Width="2*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit" Binding="{Binding ProductUnit}" Width="2*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Stock" Binding="{Binding ProductStock}" Width="2*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding ProductCode}" Width="2*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

C#:-

```
    static ObservableCollection<ProductAva> collection = new ObservableCollection<ProductAva>();
    private string ProductName { get; set; }
    private string ProductPrice { get; set; }
    private string ProductUnit { get; set; }
    private string ProductStock { get; set; }

    private string ProductCode { get; set; }


    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {




        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-KE9BBUE;Database=Vegomart;Trusted_Connection=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from AddNewItem", con);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            collection.Add(new ProductAva() { ProductName = reader.GetString(1), ProductPrice= Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(2)), ProductUnit = reader.GetString(4), ProductStock = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(5)), ProductCode = reader.GetString(3)});
        }

        pa.ItemsSource = collection;

    }
```

Please help me out..!!

Comment: There's nothing like pa.DataBind(); .... :(

Comment: I had done such task before and it happened and this time it's not :( . And Kindly if you have a solution to it so please refer it to me otherwise don't suggest me about third party sites. 

Thank You

Comment: Good luck.. this site is not here to give you answers to questions specific to `Stacloverflow site only` how do you think that most of us learned to figure things out.. we did internet searches.. sounds like you need to start with debugging your code and understanding where you went wrong in your code.. have you done that at least.. also what the heck does this mean `I had done such task before and it happened and this time it's not :( `

Comment: what you have discovered is basic knowledge.. [MSDN- Auto Implemented Property's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) but since you don't do third party sites / searches, I guess you would not have found `MSDN Site` next time do some more research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh, At last I found solution to it.

instead of declaring properties private they should be public:-

```
  private string ProductName { get; set; }
private string ProductPrice { get; set; }
private string ProductUnit { get; set; }
private string ProductStock { get; set; }
```

Correction:-

```
  public string ProductName { get; set; }
public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
public string ProductUnit { get; set; }
public string ProductStock { get; set; }
```